Use PostGIS data with node.js, Express.js in OpenLayers
I've followed the quick start guide from OpenLayers to build a new app using
node.js. So I have now a nice OSM Map (index.html + main.js), where I added already a few backgroung layers and a layerswitcher control.
All that running on localhost:5173.
Since most of the data I use is stored in PostGIS, I now want to add vector-data to the new OpenLayers map.
I followed a few basic tutorials on how to fetch data from PostgreSQL using node and express on server side,
so that I have now an express app running on localhost:3000 with a route to get GeoJSON (server.js).
Since I'm new to the node.js world, I'm having trouble on how to digest this data in my main.js file to use the data as vectorsource to create a new layer on the map.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://openlayers.org/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Using OpenLayers with Vite</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

main.js
import './style.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import {useGeographic} from 'ol/proj.js';
import {defaults as defaultControls} from 'ol/control.js';
import 'ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css';
import LayerSwitcher from 'ol-ext/control/LayerSwitcher.js';
import TileImage from 'ol/source/TileImage.js';
import LayerGroup from 'ol/layer/Group.js';

useGeographic();

var baselayers = new LayerGroup({ title: 'Hintergrund-Layer', openInLayerSwitcher: true, layers: [
   new TileLayer({
                title: 'OSM',
                baseLayer: true,
                visible: true,
                source: new OSM()
           })
    ]
});

var vectorLayers = new LayerGroup({ title: 'Vector-Layer', openInLayerSwitcher: true, layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
        title:'Sites',
        visible: true,
          source: new VectorSource({
            url: 'http:\\localhost:3000/data',
            format: new GeoJSON()
          }),
          style: {
            'stroke-color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
            'stroke-width': 2,
          }
      })

    ]
});


const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: defaultControls().extend([
            new LayerSwitcher({reordering:false})
            ]),
  layers: [
    baselayers, vectorLayers
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [6.15,49.65], 
    zoom: 11
  })
});

server.js
import express from 'express';
import pg from 'pg';
import cors from 'cors';
import dbConfig from './dbConfig.cjs';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware for CORS
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Configuration of the database connection
const { Pool } = pg;
const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);


// Route to get data out of the database
app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT gid, code, nom, area_a, ST_AsGeojson(st_transform(the_geom,4326))::json as polygon FROM hfn.gebiete Limit 10');
    res.json(result.rows);
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error! Could not retrieve any data:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Initialize the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express-Server is listening on port ${port}`);
  });

Any hint?

You write "I'm having trouble", but don't describe them. Please edit you question and describe what does not work as expected and how it does not work (errors, browser debugger console error, browser debugger network errors ...).

The data isn't simply displayed on the map. When I use a PostGIS-GeoJSON-query that creates a Feature Collection and I save this file as .geojson, it can be imported with the URL just pointing to this file and the features are displayed on the map. So is it just a question of modifying the query or do I need to reference the route (from my server.js) in a different way (inside main.js)?

Any errors in the browse debugger console or network section? If no errors, what do you see there as a result of request for vector layer data at url 'http:\localhost:3000/data'?

ST_AsGeoJSON creates valid GeoJSON Features, and your query returns a set of rows containing them - not a FeatureCollection, as hinted at in that linked repository. BTW that repo is indeed a good wrap up, however it has some minor misconceptions, too. Anyways, OL needs a FeatureCollection, and you could either use the query structure shown in that repo, or e.g. use a wrapper function - I happen to have such an aggregate version in my Gists.

I've changed the sql query in the server.js to const sql = "SELECT jsonb_build_object('type','FeatureCollection', 'features', jsonb_agg(feature)) FROM (SELECT jsonb_build_object ('type','Feature','id',gid,'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(st_transform(the_geom,4326))::jsonb,'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'the_geom') AS feature FROM (SELECT * FROM gebiete g limit 10) row) features";.  I get now a FeatureCollection starting with [{"jsonb_build_object":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features": .... In the browser I get for http://localhost:5173/localhost:3000/data an 304 Not Modified answer.

It's easier with my aggregate function wrapper, but in any case you need to extract the actual FeatureCollection object ({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [...]}). You may also need to cast the result object to TEXT for the JS OL API to make sense of it, and/or exllicitly use JSON.parse on the result, and/or explicitly define the content type to be application/json.

Thanks@geozelt but how do I get the blank FeatureCollection object out of the   ST_AsFeatureCollection, that res.json(result.rows); sends to OpenLayers?

Here as an example from official PostGIS docs (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html): SELECT json_build_object('type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json)) FROM ( VALUES (1, 'one', 'POINT(1 1)'::geometry), (2, 'two', 'POINT(2 2)'), (3, 'three', 'POINT(3 3)')) as t(id, name, geom);. Just apply principle to your geometries.

OK. in all cases I get a FeatureCollection object, that is wrapped in an ST_AsFeatureCollection or an json_build_object array. With   res.json(result.rows[0].jsonb_build_object);I get the blank FeatureCollection. But still the features do not appear on the map.

There were two issues in my code that I finally solved with the help of TomazicM and geozelot (thumb up).
To get a real FeatureCollection out of PostGIS I had to change my query in server.js to:
const sql = "SELECT jsonb_build_object('type','FeatureCollection', 'features', jsonb_agg(feature)) 
FROM (SELECT jsonb_build_object ('type','Feature','id',gid,'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(st_transform(the_geom,4326))::jsonb,'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'the_geom') AS feature 
FROM (SELECT * FROM gebiete g limit 10) row) features";

This query delivers a FeatureCollection inside an array that starts with:
[{"jsonb_build_object":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features": ....  

To get rid of the [{"jsonb_build_object": part, I adapted the code that gives back the result to:
 res.json(result.rows[0].jsonb_build_object);

The second issue was a typo in the main.js where I had to correct the url of the VectorSource from url: 'http:\\localhost:3000/data', to url: 'http://localhost:3000/data'.
Now the import of vector-data from PostGIS to OpenLayers via node.js and Express.js works fine.
